# Getting same values with srand time null in Inheritance class

Tags: c++, random, random-seed

I am trying to revise what i have learned in class and making a simple Inheritance with "Student" class.
Whenever i create a student, it creates StudentStats which is supposed to have random values in constructor as you see in the code. But i always get the same values from constructor.
I don't see what is missing, i included time.h and srand(time(null)) is in the constructor.

It may be a beginner problem but i really don't see what s wrong :/

**Here is the student class:**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Personne.h"
#include "PTUT.h"
#include "Marks.h"
#include "StudentStats.h"
#include "StudentClass.h"

using namespace std;

class PTUT;
class StudentClass;
class Etudiant : public Personne, public Marks, public StudentStats
```

**Here is the StudentStats constructor:**

```
#include "StudentStats.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>

StudentStats::StudentStats()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    Morale = (rand() % 81) + 20 ;
    MathLevel = (rand() % 81) + 20;
    ProgLevel = (rand() % 81) + 20;
    NetworkDBLevel = (rand() % 81) + 20;
    GeneralLevel = (rand() % 81) + 20;
}
```

**And the result i get (I create 4 students in main and stats of each student is separeted with "--------"):**

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt7uN.png)

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. You will probably start to notice the error yourself when you do that.

Comment: You are probably making the 4 calls that create your `student` within a very short time span, and the `time()` function has a resolution (typically) of 1 second, so each call to `srand` gets the same seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tx to Adrian Mole's comment, i got the answer.

i declared a static bool called "Seeded" and for first time i call the constructor it changes it to True from false, so next time i call the constructor it won't try to reseed.

Answer: Each time i call the constructor i reseed it (Calling srand time null for more than once) so i declared a static bool which is used to call srand time null once.

Comment: "Thank yous" should be in the comment section, BTW if you call `srand(time(NULL));` in main or wherever you create the students the problem is solved without the need of aditional variables.

Comment: Ya that was the problem. Gonna mark this answer as the correct answer in 2 days so i put it here.

Comment: if you add the explantion of why your code is wrong (dont just refer to the comment, comments can go away at any time), this can make a good answer.

Comment: If you ***really*** want, I can convert my comment into an answer. But I don't think it's ever going to  be one of Stack Overflow's Top 10! :-)  Just let me know.